# Convert HTML table to javascript array using class names

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, html-table

How do you convert an HTML table to a javascript array using the  tags's class names as the array values?
Say we have the following HTML code:

```
    <table class="grid">
      <tr>
        <td class="available"></td>
        <td class="busy"></td>
        <td class="busy"></td>
        <td class="available"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="busy"></td>
        <td class="available"></td>
        <td class="busy"></td>
        <td class="available"></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
```

I want the array to look like: [["available","busy","busy","available"],["busy","available","busy","available"]]

I have tried the following:

```
    var myTableArray = [];
    $("table#grid tr").each(function() { 
        var arrayOfThisRow = [];
        var tableData = $(this).find('td');
        if (tableData.length > 0) {
            tableData.each(function() { arrayOfThisRow.push($(this).text()); });
            myTableArray.push(arrayOfThisRow);
        }
    });
    console.log(myTableArray);
```

but it is printing an empty array as the td tags contain no text. I then tried replacing

```
    $(this).text()
```

with

```
    $(this).className()
```

but that did not work. Any suggestions?

Comment: I'm assuming the `<td>` tags are supposed to wrap the `class=...` stuff?

Comment: If you want to get the class attribute in jQuery, you should use `.attr('class')`.

Comment: @RatajS Thank you, however I replaced $(this).text() with $(this).attr('class') and it still printed an empty array. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

[`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) is the way to go.

jQuery's [`$.map`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/) is a little weird in that it seems to think [it's ok to flatten mapped arrays without asking and we're not going to fix it](https://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/10541) so you have to couch the mapped array in an array.

```js
// Cache the rows
const rows = $('.grid tr');

// `map` over each row...
const arr = $.map(rows, row => {

  // Find the row cells...
  const cells = $(row).find('td');
  
  // ...and return an array of each cell's text
  return [$.map(cells, cell => $(cell).text())];

});

console.log(arr);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="grid">
  <tr>
    <td class="available">available</td>
    <td class="busy">busy</td>
    <td class="busy">busy</td>
    <td class="available">available</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="busy">busy</td>
    <td class="available">available</td>
    <td class="busy">busy</td>
    <td class="available">available</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Alternatively, if you wanted a vanilla JS solution, you can just pick up the rows with [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll), and then iterate over them with [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), then return the text from the cell (assuming that you fix the HTML).

(Note: `[...nodelist]` is shorthand for creating an array from a nodelist so that `map` can work. You could also use [`Array.from(nodelist)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from)).

```js
// Cache the rows
const rows = document.querySelectorAll('.grid tr');

// `map` over each row...
const arr = [...rows].map(row => {

  // Find the row cells...
  const cells = row.querySelectorAll('td');

  // ...and return an array of each cell's text
  return [...cells].map(cell => cell.textContent);
});

console.log(arr);
```

```html
<table class="grid">
  <tr>
    <td class="available">available</td>
    <td class="busy">busy</td>
    <td class="busy">busy</td>
    <td class="available">available</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="busy">busy</td>
    <td class="available">available</td>
    <td class="busy">busy</td>
    <td class="available">available</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Vanilla JS Solution**

1. Get and Make array with `<tr>`
2. Map every `<tr>` and make array with `<td>` elements
3. Map only class names from every `<td>`

The example will return ARRAY from CLASS element names.

**Example:**

```js
var res = [...document.querySelectorAll('.grid tr')] // 1. Get and Make array with <tr>
    .map((el) => [...el.children] // 2. Map every <tr> and make array with <td> elements
    .map(e => e.getAttribute('class'))); // 3. Map only class names from every <td>

console.log(res);
```

```html
<table class="grid">
    <tr>
        <td class="available"></td>
        <td class="busy"></td>
        <td class="busy"></td>
        <td class="available"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="busy"></td>
        <td class="available"></td>
        <td class="busy"></td>
        <td class="available"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

This example will make ARRAY from the text content of the table.

**Example:**

```js
var res = [...document.querySelectorAll('.grid tr')] // 1. Get and Make array with <tr>
    .map((el) => [...el.children] // 2. Map every <tr> and make array with <td> elements
    .map(e => e.innerText));      // 3. Map only text content from every <td>

console.log(res);
```

```html
<table class="grid">
    <tr>
        <td>available</td>
        <td>busy</td>
        <td>busy</td>
        <td>available</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>busy</td>
        <td>available</td>
        <td>busy</td>
        <td>available</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```